# Type defaults in `floor . sqrt`

Tags: haskell

With `-Wtype-defaults` (comes with `-Wall`), `floor . sqrt . fromIntegral` gives me a hefty set of warnings even when I specify the type of the argument and the result:

```
λ> (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral) (10 :: Int) :: Int

<interactive>:356:2-6: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Double’
        (RealFrac a0)
          arising from a use of ‘floor’ at <interactive>:356:2-6
        (Floating a0)
          arising from a use of ‘sqrt’ at <interactive>:356:10-13
        (Num a0)
          arising from a use of ‘fromIntegral’ at <interactive>:356:17-28
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘floor’
      In the expression: floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
      In the expression: (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral) (10 :: Int) :: Int

<interactive>:356:2-6: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Double’
        (RealFrac a0)
          arising from a use of ‘floor’ at <interactive>:356:2-6
        (Floating a0)
          arising from a use of ‘sqrt’ at <interactive>:356:10-13
        (Num a0)
          arising from a use of ‘fromIntegral’ at <interactive>:356:17-28
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘floor’
      In the expression: floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
      In the expression: (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral) (10 :: Int) :: Int
3
```

I was able to get around this by specifying a nonpolymorphic type for `fromIntegral`:

```
λ> (floor . sqrt . (fromIntegral :: Int -> Double)) (10 :: Int) :: Int
3
```

The following also works, but is even more cumbersome:

```
λ> (floor . sqrt . (fromIntegral :: (Integral a) => a -> Double)) (10 :: Int) :: Int
3
```

My questions are:

- Is there an easier way around the type default warnings? (Turning off `-Wtype-defaults` does not qualify.)
- Is this the right way to calculate the value of this composite function (floor of square root) in Haskell? Having to use `fromIntegral` and having to specify the intermediate type reminds me of the proverb "simple things are difficult."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three types to choose (the input type, the intermediate floating-point type used internally, and the result type), and you have to somehow tell the compiler about all three. There's lots of combinations for fixing them each, but you can't get shorter than three.

I think `TypeApplications` are a particularly convenient way to specify these types. Here's one way to start from your original, which had two annotations, and add just one to avoid defaulting:

```
> :set -XTypeApplications -Wtype-defaults
> (floor . sqrt @Double . fromIntegral) (10 :: Int) :: Int
3
```

Here's another that might be more ergonomical (because it is more flexible about exactly where parentheses go):

```
> (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral @Int @Double) 10 :: Int
3
```

I like the idea of your third example, which is to modify your second example so that you don't have to repeat `Int`, and therefore avoid a potential point of fragility. You can achieve this in a slightly less cumbersome way with type applications by making use of the special `_` type application, which lets the compiler use the usual inference procedure for one of the type variables:

```
> (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral @_ @Double) (10 :: Int) :: Int
3
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is this the right way to calculate the value of this composite function (floor of square root) in Haskell? Having to use `fromIntegral` and having to specify the intermediate type reminds me of the proverb "simple things are difficult."

You are ultimately calculating an integer square root, so ideally you'd want to avoid routing your calculation through `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`. You might. for instance, use [`integerSquareRoot :: Integral a => a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.8.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers.html#v:integerSquareRoot) from the *arithmoi* library.

As for your first question, I second [Daniel Wagner's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52537987/2751851) of using the `TypeApplications` extension to specify the intermediate type.

Comment: Nice. I answered "how should I specify types in my program", but this question answers "what code should I put in my program" -- arguably the more important thing to talk about.

Comment: Very good point. The context of the situation is illustrating the expressive power of Haskell to absolute beginners. I would therefore like to avoid libraries and extensions. Given I had two questions in my question, I was asking for trouble since I can only select one to be the correct one. Because Daniel's answer also addresses the use of default language features and libraries (by verifying that three types have to be specified), I chose that as the correct one. This one was upvoted too, naturally. The _arithmoi_ library seems to be actively maintained, which is a good sign.